# How to access the global javascript method using angular $window object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

How to access the global javascript function using angularJS $window object and assign/bind it to the ng-model/scope variable?
Have a javascript method defined outside scope of angular, need to access that method and get the returned value and assign/set it to scope variable!
[LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/EaXbLDCvsRlMO0PXTfqM?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't be declaring methods outside of Angular.  [Use a service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).  If you absolutely need to bind a global method to the scope:

```
$scope.myFunc = $window.myFunc;
```

You can see a working solution in [This plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XyA1CrULTw6r31NoRZ5n?p=preview)

Comment: Have implemented your logic but still am not able to bind the value to view; http://plnkr.co/edit/EaXbLDCvsRlMO0PXTfqM?p=preview

Comment: @JohnSmith That's because you're trying to assign a function to a model.

Comment: My Mistake! Updated the plnk : http://plnkr.co/edit/EaXbLDCvsRlMO0PXTfqM?p=preview

Comment: You also did not use the $window object, and in order to use the $window object you need to add it as a dependency. See [updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/aWrENxUVANxRLEsLZnvB?p=preview)

Comment: @JoseM is correct, if you want to use array injection, you need to declare the `$window` dependency twice.

Comment: Is it possible to have a $watch on $window object?

Comment: @JohnSmith there's a large difference between 'possible' and 'should'.  Your efforts are better spent re-factoring the external function into a service.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can define that function with $rootScope which should be available everywhere throughout the app. Like

```
$rootScope.exposeMeAnyWhere=function(){
      return "value";
}
```